# What is the use case for inherent transactions?

Tags: substrate-node-template, transactions

Just for curiosity!

In what conditions we can use Inherent transactions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> With this type of transaction, block authoring nodes can add
> information directly to a block. Inherent transactions can only be
> inserted into a block by the block authoring node that calls them.
> Typically, this type of transaction is not gossiped to other nodes or
> stored in the transaction queue. The data inserted using an inherent
> transaction is assumed to be valid without requiring specific
> validation.
>
> As an example, the pallet_timestamp::Call::now function enables a
> block authoring node to insert a current timestamp in each block the
> node produces.

- https://docs.substrate.io/learn/transaction-types/#inherent-transactions

Typically when you want to insert external information (transaction) relevant to your runtime (e.g. a timestamp) and the source of the transaction is the block authoring node itself.

I like to think of them as system-level transactions that keep the chain running smoothly.

If you see a purpose for such a transaction in your runtime then there is the use case.

Related

- https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5816/29

Comment: can we use inherent transactions for fetching data through an api?